# JMeter Integration With Azure Pipeline and after execution of test getting as directory not found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance, azure-devops, cicd

As Part of Jmeter Integration With Azure Pipeline and after execution of test getting as below errors:
1.Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 3 is not equal to fixed size 5
[image]
2.Html report is not getting generated.
[image]

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering from [JMeter issue 5591](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/5591) which was fixed 2 years ago.

The solution is upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

The alternative solution is downgrading to [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/)